# Display Artefacts when Switching Pages in TMS TAdvOfficePager

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, tms

I'm using `TAdvOfficePager`component from [TMS Software](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/aop.asp). Inside each page I use a frame. When switching between pages I get some ugly display artefacts like this:

[image]

The controls from the old page and the controls from the new page are both visible for some time.

Is there anything I can do about this?

*Note*: There's nothing happening in the `OnShow` event handler, it's really just the page switch causing the artefact.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

tms have a lot of problem in theirs components. solutions:

1) try redraw the component
2) sometimes enable->false and then enable->true can solve it(also try with visible)
3) take the code, digg in it and resolve the problem by yourself....

best regards,

Comment: Thanks! Where would you put all that? In the `OnShow` event handler?

Comment: Tried those, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Maybe I really have to looke at some code.